# Trying to pass an object to a function?

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to send **array** (which is an object?) that contains random integers. I want to send the array to **sort()** in order to sort the array, but when I am parsing **array** to **sort()** I get the following error: `error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type`. Please, if you are changing anything in the code, please please explain what you are doing and why you are doing it because **I am already confused about the code as it is right now**.

**I am not allowed to change the code in array.c or array.h, and void_sort()'s argument can not be changed**.

**array.c**

```
struct array {
    int* data;
    int size;
};

struct array* array_create()
{
    struct array* array = (struct array*) malloc(sizeof(struct array));
    array->data = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * 10000);
    array->size = 10000;
    return array;
}
```

**array.h**

```
typedef struct array* ARRAY;

ARRAY array_create();
```

**main.c**

```
void sort (int A[], int N) 
{
    // Sort the array
}

ARRAY array;
array = array_create();
sort(array->data, 100);  // This gives me error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

Comment: If `sort()` doesn't see the full (complete) definition of `struct array`, then you can't do this. Also, [do ***NOT*** cast the return value of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)!

Comment: @mah No, that's not what the problem is.

Comment: @mah Hmm, the thing is that I have a header file called **sort.h** and it contains `void  sort      (int* A, int N);`. The `void sort (int A[], int N) ` (that you can see in **main.c**) is actually in an own file called **sort.c**. I am so confused because I can't see that **sort.h** is calling **sort.c** anywhee.......

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the declaration of the array `struct` to `array.h`. The error you are getting is because that type is not known in `main.c`. You can use pointers to an undefined type, but you cannot access its members.

If you want to keep the implementation hidden, you can create access functions. Add to array.h:

```
int *array_data(ARRAY array);
int array_size(ARRAY array);
```

and to array.c:

```
int *array_data(ARRAY array) { return array->data; }
int array_size(ARRAY array) { return array->size; }
```

and in main.c:

```
sort(array_data(array), array_size(array));
```

Comment: Ok, but why can I not just pass the whole **array** to **sort()**? So instead of typing `sort(array->data, 100);` I am typing `sort(array, 100);`?

Comment: I still think this has something to do with this: Hmm, the thing is that I have a header file called **sort.h** and it contains `void  sort      (int* A, int N);`. The `void sort (int A[], int N) ` (that you can see in **main.c**) is actually in an own file called **sort.c**. I am so confused because I can't see that **sort.h** is calling **sort.c** anywhere...

Comment: ^Thus because when I am calling `void sort(array->data, 100);` I get the error "Undefined reference to sort".

Comment: @user3285214 but then that's not a compiler error, that's a linker error, and it has nothing to do with your header files.

Comment: That *is* a compiler error. A linker error would be something like "undefined reference to something". The error here occurs because the compiler only knows ARRAY is a pointer to some struct (in main.cpp), and it cannot know what is *inside* that struct.

Comment: @C Yes it is working now because I put the struct in array.h. But I get the "undefined reference to sort" when I am typing `sort(array->data, 100);`. This is because there is nothing that links sort.h and sort.c together. Sort.h contains `void sort (int* A, int N);` and sort.c contains `void sort (int A[], int N);`.

Comment: Ok. If you have `void sort (int* A, int N);` in sort.h, you need `void sort (int* A, int N) { /* sorting logic */ }` in sort.c.

Comment: And of course you need to compile all three ".c" files together. Something like `gcc array.c sort.c main.c`.

Comment: @C Ah yes, I didn't compile the sort.c file, heh... But I still don't understand how **sort.h** and **sort.c** gets connected. No one includes each other? :S

Comment: The compiler only needs to know that the function exists, its name and parameters, when it generates code for the invocation in main.c. And the linker later finds the function implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move this from array.c to array.h:

```
struct array {
    int* data;
    int size;
};
```

That's because this declares the array type.  If you don't want to do that, you can copy-paste it into main.c, and everyone will hate you but you'll accomplish your objective of not modifying array.h or array.c.